# Triangle mesh in opengl

Tags: opengl, mesh

I'm trying to generate a simple triangle mesh in opengl.

I can't realy find anything online. Can some one help with link to a tutorial or explain a basic idea how to please?

Comment: We need to know which version of OpenGL you are using and what language you are developing with.

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL does not (generally) *generate* triangular meshes. It can *render* them, but that's a different question. And pretty much any [tutorial on OpenGL](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_started#Tutorials_and_How_To_Guides) will show you some way of rendering them.

Comment: Does it not generate meshes in a geometry shader?